# ¿Cómo agregar una lista dentro de otra C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, lista, arraylist

Resulta que estaba probando el uso de roles para un determinado usuario, y tenía los siguientes datos en duro lo cual me funcionaba:

```
    listAccounts.Add(new Account { Username = "acc1", Password = "123", Roles = new String[] {"superadmin", "admin", "employee"} });
    listAccounts.Add(new Account { Username = "acc2", Password = "123", Roles = new String[] {"admin", "employee"} }); 
    listAccounts.Add(new Account { Username = "acc3", Password = "123", Roles = new String[] {"employee"} });
```

Lo que deseo hacer ahora es obtenerlo desde una tabla de la base de datos, lo cual estaba intentándolo hacer de la siguiente forma:

```
public AccountModel() {
    DataTable dt_usuarios = new DataTable();
    DataTable dt_roles = new DataTable();   
    String sql = "SELECT username,password FROM usuarios";
    conexion.conectar();
    MySqlDataAdapter datos = new MySqlDataAdapter(sql, conexion.con);        
    datos.Fill(dt_usuarios);
    List<String> roles_list = new List<String>();
    foreach (DataRow user_name in dt_usuarios.Rows)
    {           
        String sql_roles = "SELECT r.rol FROM roles r,userroles ur,usuarios u WHERE u.username='" + user_name[0].ToString() + "' AND u.id_usuarios=ur.id_usuarios AND ur.id_roles=r.id_roles";
        MySqlDataAdapter datos_roles = new MySqlDataAdapter(sql_roles, conexion.con);            
        datos_roles.Fill(dt_roles);
        foreach (DataRow roles_user in dt_roles.Rows)
        {
            roles_list.Add(roles_user[0].ToString());
        }

        listAccounts.Add(new Account { Username = user_name[0].ToString(), Password = user_name[1].ToString(), Roles = new String[] { roles_list } });
    }
    conexion.cerrar();
    //listAccounts.Add(new Account { Username = "acc1", Password = "123", Roles = new String[] {"superadmin", "admin", "employee"} });
    //listAccounts.Add(new Account { Username = "acc2", Password = "123", Roles = new String[] {"admin", "employee"} });

    //listAccounts.Add(new Account { Username = "acc3", Password = "123", Roles = new String[] {"employee"} });
}
```

Pero cuando le asigno a `Roles = new String[]` la lista `roles_list` me da error diciendo que no se puede convertir del tipo `Generic.List<string>` a `string`.

Me gustaría saber cómo enviar la lista de `string` llamada `roles_list` al componente de la lista `Roles`, tal como lo estaba intentando.

Comment: Recuerda evitar el uso de consultas dinámicas ya que es suceptible a `SQL Injection`, [aquí la documentación oficial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx)

Comment: En lugar de `roles_list.Add(roles_user[0].ToString());` intenta ponerlo con el nombre de la columna, esto, primero validando que exista el registro `roles_list.Add(roles_user["rol"].ToString());`

Comment: Hola @Flxtr, existe la forma de protegerse de SQL Injection al usar consultas dinamicas?, me imagino que con Store Procedure se podría hacer con algun sentencia?
Gracias

Comment: Es posible protegerse usando consultas dinámicas si haces uso de parámetros, en el punto 3 del documento que te pasé en el primer comentario viene la forma, justo donde dice **`Step 3. Use Parameters with Dynamic SQL`**. Otra forma, es utilizando *Stored Procedures*, aquí ya depende de qué forma te guste más (el documento está en inglés pero también puedes cambiarle el idioma a español si así lo deseas)

Comment: En caso de utilizar Stored Procedures, podría de ser de cualquier forma? o habría que hacer alguna validación o incluir alguna sentencia de codigo?

Answer (score 2):

El problema te lo indica el compilador: es un error de casteo.

El atributo `Roles` es un vector de `string`s, no una lista de `string`s. Así que tenemos dos opciones:

Cambiar el tipo de dato `Roles` en tu clase `Account`, de `String[]` a `List<string>`. Puedes hacerlo, pero habría que revisar que el cambio no genere problemas en otras partes del código.

La segunda opción sería cambiar el tipo de dato de `roles_list` a `String[X]`. Y cambiar el código en el `foreach` por:

```
String[] roles_list = new String[10];
int contador = 0;
foreach (DataRow roles_user in dt_roles.Rows)
{
    roles_list[contador] = roles_user[0].ToString();
    contador++;
}
```

La contra es que se necesita indicar un tamaño al vector, por lo que podrías quedarte con posiciones de memoria sin utilizar, o bien que te hagan falta.

Comment: Buen punto, está intentando hacer uso de un tipo de dato cuando realmente está declarando otro. En lo personal preferiría declarar `Roles` como una lista de `string`s y listo, se termina el problema

Answer (score 1):

Deber definir el nombre de tu lista, donde `Accounts` es el nombre de tu clase.

```
List<Accounts> listAccounts= new List<Accounts>();
```

La clase `Accounts` la puedes definir de la siguiente manera:

```
public class Accounts 
{
    public string Usuario
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string Password
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public List<string> Roles
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public Accounts(string usuario, string password, List<string> roles){
        this.Usuario = usuario;
        this.Password = password;
        this.Roles = roles;
    }
}
```

Y para agregar elementos a tu lista:

```
listAccounts.Add(new Accounts (user_name[0].ToString(), user_name[1].ToString(),  { roles_list } );
```

Donde `roles_list` son los elementos de tu Segunda Lista

Comment: El problema persiste, dado que el atributo Roles es un vector, y el tipo de dato que está ingresando es una lista.

Comment: He editado mi respuesta, saludos

Answer (score 0):

Se puede usar el parametro .ToArray para añadir una lista a un array.

```
string[] resultado;
List<string> almacenTemporal = new List<string>();
resultado = almacenTemporal.ToArray();
```

Así me ha funcionado.